# Should I talk about my new salary in a promotion?

Tags: salary, job-change, human-resources, brazil

My coworker that got me this job left, leaving me alone at the front-end in the company. In doing so, the company's director gave me a promotion, saying that he would pay for any course I needed to do (and he did).

This happened like almost 2 months ago.
1 Week before this they got my work permit to update my new salary, and then I receive this promotion.

The deal is: After almost 2 months they didn't return my permit, and I still with the same salary.

**Should I talk about this? If so, with whom? The HR or my manager?**

Note: It wasn't my manager's that got me the promotion, but the director's.
Also, I'm only here for 8 months.

For cultural background, I'm from Brazil.

Comment: Is your job also in Brazil? (Since you have a permit, I'm assuming you work abroad?) Also, do you have the promise of new salary/promotion in writing?

Comment: @Erik Yeah, I don't really know if "permit" is the right translate to what I meant. It is just the document that proves I'm working in the company.
And no, I don't have this new promise in writing, but I have a witness of the agreement (we we're at 3 at the offering proposal) We didn't discuss numbers, just told me that It would be a raise at market level.
Also, yes, I do work in Brazil

Comment: You mean they took your work contract? Why would they need that? They have their own copy of it, right?

Comment: @Erik nope, its not a contract. Its just a document that we use here in Brazil to prove that you are working on a company legally, as a employee. There it is writed both mine and the company's information plus my salary.
It is updated always that has some changes in my role, but its not normal that they didn't give it back yet.

Comment: Just ask them (presumably whomever you gave the document to), there's nothing that needs to be handled particularly carefully here - you just need to remind and/or get an update. Also, you should always (at least) make a copy of an important document before giving it to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I talk about this? If so, with whom? The HR or my manager?

**Short answer, yes you should, but not with HR or your manager.**

I would start the conversation with the **companies director who gave you the promotion**.  Spell out the facts, and see where the conversation takes you.  Obviously show a copy of the contract, and inquire as to the status of the permit.

If it doesn't help, then at this point you can take the issue to HR and see if they can help, but if the companies director isn't able to or willing to help this option may be a long shot.

This is one of those cases where if you don't start inquiring as to the status of your promotion (and your permit), nothing will happen.